# How to create django model without primary key column and avoiding Id default column

Tags: python, sql-server, django

I am using SQL Server as a default database. I replicated the SQL Server table in the model using inspectdb command. Now, SQL Server table does not have any primary key column. So, django model automatically creates id as a primary key and giving me error while posting the data.

> column "id" does not exist

Is there any work around to remove id at the same time not defining primary key on any columns of the model?

```
from django.db import models

class ImptCustomer(models.Model):
    customerid = models.IntegerField(db_column='CustomerId', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    name = models.CharField(db_column='Name', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    phonenumber = models.CharField(db_column='PhoneNumber', max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    emailaddress = models.CharField(db_column='EmailAddress', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    streetline = models.CharField(db_column='StreetLine', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    city = models.CharField(db_column='City', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    statecode = models.CharField(db_column='StateCode', max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    postalcode = models.CharField(db_column='PostalCode', max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    customer_key = models.IntegerField(db_column='Customer_Key', blank=True, null=True, editable = False)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'IMPT_Customer'
```

Comment: can't you use the `customerid` to be the primary key? how can a SQL table not have a pk?

Comment: @dirkgroten It's a staging table so generally it does not have any Primary Key.

Comment: Django models won't work unless you have a primary key, that too single. Composite is not supported. A workaround may be to use cursor from Django.db

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't explicitly define a primary key, then the id becomes your primary key. So you cannot do that.

Comment: And that id column must be present in SQL Server database table right? But I cannot alter the table and add id column. Table cannot be modified.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible with Django's ORM:

> Each model requires exactly one field to have primary_key=True (either explicitly declared or automatically added).

(see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields))

Answer (score 1):

I guess it can work like that:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields

```
from django.db import models

class ImptCustomer(models.Model):
    customerid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='CustomerId')  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'IMPT_Customer'
```

Comment: But in this case I cannot put customerid as null or duplicate

Comment: I don't know u can try, but why do you use id if you need it to be null / duplicate ... ? That weird.

Answer (score 0):

SQL have no strict requirement that primary key must be unique, so you may do the trick:

```py
class ImptCustomer(models.Model):
    customerid = models.IntegerField(
        primary_key=True,
        unique=False,
        default=None,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        db_column='CustomerId'
    )
```

Sure you must generate primary key values for new records manually, but if you have exist database with data it may be just single solution for it.